# At what point does LINQ become too terse?

Tags: linq, procedural-programming

At what point does LINQ become too terse and procedural techniques resorted to?

Answer (score 3):

Terseness is in the eye of the beholder. When you're not comfortable with the code anymore, then it's time to refactor it a bit. The refactoring could be swapping to some procedural bits, or breaking your linq queries apart, or whatever it takes to make it understandable again. As long as the **intent** of the code is obvious, it shouldn't matter how terse it is or what techniques are used to achieve the end goal :-)

Comment: I'd even go so far as to say that terse but clear (as to intent) code is a very good idea.

Comment: LINQ is certainly dense, but I kind of like it that way. I hate it when there's so much junk and extra whitespace that you can't get a feel for what the big picture is. LINQ query + comment (if necessary) is very easy to grok quickly. Long procedures often need a bit of mental agility required - sure you can understand what's happening on any given line, but patching it all together in your head to figure out what it's actually *doing* can be a lot more time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Any language construct, not just LINQ, is too terse when the majority of people on your group cannot quickly understand what a line of code is doing.

Comment: I agree, but I also dare say that this is only part of the picture: I believe the intent of a line of code can be incomprehensible due to other reasons than terseness alone. Perhaps in cases where variable names aren't self-explanatory (e.g. because they're cryptic or misleading) and therefore one fails to grasp the full meaning of the statement around it.

Answer (score 0):

When you can no longer do what is required to be done (easily).